# dependency not found

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dependencies, gtk

I am trying to install crossover for linux, on my Ubuntu 20.04 Mate installation, but the dependency python-gtk2 is missing.

```
sudo apt-get install python-gtk2 

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-gtk2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python-gtk2' has no installation candidate
```

I tried getting an older version for Ubuntu 18.04, but that wont install either.
it says the project is depreciated. That's all well and good, but I need it to run crossover.

[image]

what shall I do to satisfy this dependency?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess I failed to mention having had a previous version of crossover already installed, which turns out was important. Installing using the deb file installer, showed no errors, during install, which made me think it was irrelevant.

in any event, I did `sudo apt-get purge crossover`, then ran the binary generic shell installer, which then ran successfully, and now crossover is now installed.

Answer (score 0):

As you are running 20.04, I'm going to assume you are not trying to download https://download.cnet.com/CrossOver-for-Linux/3000-2094_4-75761258.html, but that instead you are trying to get https://linux.softpedia.com/get/Office/Office-Suites/CrossOver-3883.shtml - if I'm wrong, please let me know.

AFAIK, crossover is a commercial product, and they probably have a pretty good level of customer support.  Ubuntu and this site may not have great support for this paid product.

If, on the otherhand, you are trying to use the free product last updated in 2013, you may need to go to some efforts to try and get this running with your system.

Comment: I have the official download, from crossover. So, no, I am not using softpedia's version

Comment: I thought I read that the official download is a binary executable?  And which version of crossover do you have?  Their [installation instructions](https://www.codeweavers.com/support/wiki/linux/faq/Ubuntu) do not seem to reference any older depandancies

Comment: K - I fired up a VM and installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 - then downloaded crossover_20.0.4-1.deb - This installed missing libc6-i286, but `sudo apt install -f` fixed that.  I think perhaps you do not have the correct version of crossover.